# Is there a way to upsert a list with a single query?

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I know this question has been asked before, but that's a different scenario.
I'd like to have a collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11d"),
    "pk": 1,
    "forums": [{
        "pk": 1,
        "thread_count": 10, 
        "post_count": 20,
    }, {
        "pk": 2,
        "thread_count": 5, 
        "post_count": 24,
    }]
}
```

What I want to do is to upsert a "forum" item, incrementing counters or adding an item if it does not exist.

For example to do something like this (I hope it makes sense):

```
db.mycollection.update({
    "pk": 3,
    "forums.pk": 2
}, {
    "$inc": {"forums.$.thread_count": 1},
    "$inc": {"forums.$.post_count": 1},
}, true)
```

and have:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11d"),
    "pk": 1,
    "forums": [{
        "pk": 1,
        "thread_count": 10, 
        "post_count": 20,
    }, {
        "pk": 2,
        "thread_count": 5, 
        "post_count": 24,
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11e"),
    "pk": 3,
    "forums": [{
        "pk": 2,
        "thread_count": 1, 
        "post_count": 1,
    }]
}
```

I can surely make it in three steps:

1. Upsert the whole collection with a new item
2. addToSet the forum item to the list
3. increment forum item counters with positional operator

That's to say:

```
db.mycollection.update({pk:3}, {pk:3}, true)
db.mycollection.update({pk:3}, {$addToSet: {forums: {pk:2}}})
db.mycollection.update({pk:3, 'forums.pk': 2}, {$inc: {'forums.$.thread_counter': 1, {'forums.$.post_counter': 1}})
```

Are you aware of a more efficient way to do it?
TIA, Germano

Answer (score 10):

As you may have discovered, the [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) cannot be used in upserts:

> The positional operator cannot be combined with an `upsert` since it requires a matching array element. If your update results in an insert then the "$" will literally be used as the field name.

So you won't be able to achieve the desired result in a single query.

You *have* to separate the creation of the document from the counter update. Your own solution is on the right track. It can be condensed into the following two queries:

```
// optionally create the document, including the array
db.mycollection.update({pk:3}, {$addToSet: {forums: {pk:2}}}, true)

// update the counters in the array item
db.mycollection.update({pk:3, 'forums.pk': 2}, {$inc: {'forums.$.thread_counter': 1, 'forums.$.post_counter': 1}})
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Thanks anyway.