# Updating values in array field if criteria matches else inserting MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have seen multiple instances of the question i'm asking but none seems to solve my problem.

I have a collection of documents with schema:

```
{
 _id:someId,
 brands:[
 {_id:1,name:Nike,products:[]},
 {_id:2,name:Reebok,products:[]}     
 ]
}
```

what i want to do is update the array field if any of the array element matches else insert a new object in the brands array.

So far i have come across this:

```
  var args = {
      'query': {_id:someId,"brands._id":someBrandId,}
    , 'update': {
      "$set": {
        'brands.$.products':req.tempStore.products
      }
    },
    , 'upsert':true
  };
```

and then i'm using the nodejs driver and used the following:

```
db.companies.findAndModify(args,function(err,document){
 if(err) return next(err);
 //some other logic here

})
```

On executing the above if it finds the object exists inside the brands array it successfully updates it but if it doesn't it gives the following error:

**Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array**

i don't have any clue how to add a new value in the array field if it doesn't exists.

Comment: MongoDb can't use a positional operator with an `upsert`. Logically, it makes sense as you're trying to modify a specific array element (and it's structure), yet one doesn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to upsert a list with a single query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467480/is-there-a-way-to-upsert-a-list-with-a-single-query)